# Upload Multiple Images Via Flask and Store List In JSON

Tags: python, json, list, flask

It is where I am uploading multiple images through Python Flask (this is all fine as the all selected images upload and save to the correct folder with correct name types etc.) The issue is saving the list of the images uploaded into a JSON. I have it so far where the value in the JSON is a list and it saves one image name to the list, but cannot seem to for loop through the other image names to save the others as well?
I'm also not sure if the .split is correct in the storyTimeMap function in the Python file, I have used this in an other project and made sense to use it here? 
Any help is appreciated

MAIN PYTHON FILE:

```
def storyTimeMap(form, filename):
    storyTime = {}
    storyTime["Title"] = form["Title"]
    storyTime["ParaOne"] = form["StoryPara"]
    storyTime["ParaTwo"] = form["StoryParaTwo"]
    storyTime["ParaThree"] = form["StoryParaThree"]
    storyTime["ParaFour"] = form["StoryParaFour"]
    storyTime["Quote"] = form["Quote"]
    storyTime["schoolSelect"] = form["schoolSelect"]
    storyTime["filename"] = filename.split()
    return storyTime

@app.route("/textupload/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def text():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'filename' not in request.files:
            flash("No Image Uploaded, Try Again")
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['filename']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash("No File Selected, Try Again")
            return refirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            for f in request.files.getlist("filename"):
                f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename))
                print "THIS IS MULIPLE IMAGES?"
                print f.filename
            # filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            # file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    if request.method == "POST" and "Title" in request.form:
        data[request.form["Title"]] = storyTimeMap(request.form, f.filename)
        with open('/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/newstories.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
        flash("Your Story Has Been Posted!")
        return render_template("main.html", data=data, filename=filename)
    return render_template("textupload.html", data=data)
```

HTML FORM:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}
<body>

<div class="container">
<h3>Upload a Story!</h3>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <fieldset>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Story Title" name="Title">
      <p></p>
      <textarea  type ="text" class ="form-control" placeholder ="Paragragh One" name="StoryPara" rows = "3"></textarea>
      <p></p>
      <textarea type ="text" class ="form-control" placeholder ="Paragragh Two" name="StoryParaTwo" rows = "3"></textarea>
      <p></p>
      <textarea type ="text" class ="form-control" placeholder ="Paragragh Three" name="StoryParaThree" rows = "3"></textarea>
      <p></p>
      <textarea type ="text" class ="form-control" placeholder ="Paragragh Four" name="StoryParaFour" rows = "3"></textarea>
      <p></p>
      <p>School:</p>
      <select class="form-control" name="schoolSelect">
        <option>School of Computing</option>
        <option>School of Engineering and Built Environment</option>
        <option>School of Business</option>
        <option>School of Applied Sciences</option>
        <option>School of Arts and Creative Industries</option>
        <option>School of Health and Social Care</option>
      </select>
      <p></p>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quote" name="Quote">
      <p></p>
      <input type=file name=filename multiple>
      <p></p>
      <input class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" value="Submit">
      <p></p>
    <a href="/admin" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Admin Page</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

JSON FILE (filename is a list but only stores one filename):

```
{
 "TEST TEN MULTI": {
    "ParaFour": "hfswrthwrth",
    "ParaOne": "ADGEQRG",
    "ParaThree": "srthbsfghwrt",
    "ParaTwo": "ADFGADFS",
    "Quote": "whshrrssth",
    "Title": "TEST TEN MULTI",
    "filename": [
      "bart-simpson_c_200x200.png"
    ],
    "schoolSelect": "School of Computing"
  },
  "VERSION 3": {
    "ParaFour": "qefgkljenglkqejrn",
    "ParaOne": "sdkjcah alight dskjhv kljabds",
    "ParaThree": "reqlifhdskljgnekrlg",
    "ParaTwo": "vadfgdfkghiausdnv",
    "Quote": "radgfdwguahflkjdsn",
    "Title": "VERSION 3",
    "filename": "HomeFuels-Direct-truck-200x200.png",
    "schoolSelect": "School of Computing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looping through the images in your `text` handler function, you can save the filenames in a list, and pass that list as a param to your `storyTimeMap` function. Something like this:

```
def text():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'filename' not in request.files:
            flash("No Image Uploaded, Try Again")
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['filename']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash("No File Selected, Try Again")
            return refirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            file_list = []
            for f in request.files.getlist("filename"):
                file_list.append(f.filename)
                f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename))
                print "THIS IS MULIPLE IMAGES?"
                print f.filename
```

And then you can pass the list when you call your `storyTimeMap` function:

`data[request.form["Title"]] = storyTimeMap(request.form, file_list)`

At the moment, you seem to be passing just the name of the last image to your `storyTimeMap` function. Which explains why you are getting only one filename in the list.

Then instead of doing this:

```
storyTime["filename"] = filename.split()
```

you can just assign the list like this instead:

```
storyTime["filename"] = file_list
```